# How do I display data in Chart.js that isn't represented by a label?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, histogram, geojson

I am building an app that allows users to search for data related to meteorite landings. Users can tailor their search based on name, century, and mass. I'm currently struggling to complete the histogram as part of the Summary Metrics component. I've dropped my code below.

When a search is performed, data is displayed on a table (and map if toggled). In table mode, users can click the Summary metrics button. The labels for the x-axis represent the years from the lowest to the highest. However, there is only enough space for 10 labels. If the user chooses the 1800s as a search parameter, the labels will be 1800, 1811, 1822, and so on.

Sadly, unless there is data consistent with meteorite landings on the specific years indicated by the labels, it won't be shown. How can I alter my code so that I can keep the labels equidistant, but represent data from any year in the century on the histogram?

Many thanks!

```
/*================SUMMARY METRICS COMPONENT================*/

const ctx = document.getElementById('histogram').getContext('2d');
let chartYears = null;
let yearsArr = null;
let strikesArr = null;
let sumMetActive = false;


summaryMetricsBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

    chartLabels();

    const totalStrikes = document.querySelector(".total-strikes");
    const avgMass = document.querySelector(".avg-mass");

    totalStrikes.innerHTML = `Total Strikes: ${finalItems.length}`;
    avgMass.innerHTML = `Average Mass: ${massCalculation()} grams`;

    sumMetActive = true;

    if(contentDisplay.classList.contains("map-mode")) {
        leafletMap.style.display = "none";
        summaryMetrics.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        
        resultsTableContainer.style.display = "none";
        summaryMetrics.style.display = "block";
    }
})

function chartLabels() {
    
    const years = finalItems.map(item => item.properties.year);

    const minYear = Math.min(...years);
    const maxYear = Math.max(...years);

    const yearRange = maxYear - minYear;

    const intervalSize = Math.floor(yearRange / 9);

    const chartYears = Array.from({ length: 9 }, (_, index) => minYear + index * intervalSize);
    console.log(minYear);

    chartYears.push(maxYear);

    strikesByYearCalc(chartYears);
}

function strikesByYearCalc(years) {
    const strikesByYear = Array(years.length).fill(0);

    finalItems.forEach(item => {
        const yearIndex = years.indexOf(item.properties.year);
        if (yearIndex !== -1) {
            strikesByYear[yearIndex]++;
        }
    });
    
    chartFunc(years, strikesByYear);
}

const massCalculation = () => {
    console.log(finalItems);
    let totalMass = 0;
    finalItems.forEach(item => {
        totalMass += item.properties.mass;
    })
    // console.log(totalMass / finalItems.length);
    return totalMass / finalItems.length;
}

function chartFunc(years, strikesByYear) {

    console.log(years);
    console.log(strikesByYear);

    const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: years,
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Strikes by Year',
          data: strikesByYear,
          backgroundColor: ["#FFDC73"],
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: false,
            barPercentage: 1.3,
            ticks: {
              max: 3,
              maxRotation: 90,
              minRotation: 90,
            }
          }, {
            display: true,
            ticks: {
              autoSkip: false,
              max: 4,
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });

}
```